# Angular 2, Adding calc() as inline style. Unsafe interpolation using parentheses

Tags: javascript, angular, interpolation

**Angular 2 rc3**

I am trying to dynamically add `calc()` to an element in a template. I have something like this.

```
template : `<div attr.style.width="{{width}}></div>"`

export myClass
{
    @Input() myInputObject:any;
    private width:string;


   ngOnInit() { this.setWidth()}

   private setWidth()
   {
       let percent = myInputObject.percent;
       this.width =  'calc(' + percent + '% - 20px)';
   }
}
```

If I use the parenthesis the ouput looks like this in the DOM.

`<div style="unsafe"></div>`

If I take out the parenthesis it works (sort of) It looks like this.

`<div style="calc10% - 20px"></div>`

This also doesn't work.

```
<div attr.style.width="calc({{width}} - 20px)">
```

Any help on how to add `calc()` to the template is much appreciated. Note I also tried replacing the parenthesis with `&#40;` and `&#41;`. That also came back as "unsafe".

**Example: (rc1)**

I am using rc3 in my environment. But I was able to reproduce the same issue with RC1 in plunker. I am assuming this is a security thing. But there must be a way to add `calc()` to a style attribute. Maybe there is a better way than this?

https://plnkr.co/edit/hmx5dL72teOyBWCOL0Jm?p=preview

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Calculated styles should be **sanitized**.

Here is the solution for you:

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
  template: `
    <div [style.width]="width">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {

  private width:string;

  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
    this.name = 'World'
    this.width = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("calc(10% - 20px)");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this out sometime today and get back to you.

Comment: Note that in RC6 I needed to use DomSanitizer instead of DomSanitizationService.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html

Comment: It's not working in Mozilla Firefox. In Chrome and IE it works, any help?

Comment: Can you explain why calculated styles should be sanitized?

Answer (score 10):

You can also try using ngStyle instead:

```
[ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc(' + percent + '% - 20px)'}"
```

And just bind 'percent' value to the input value.