# Angular: Correct way to use calc in style binding

Tags: angular

What is the correct way to bind calc() to style.height, style.width in angular?

I have:

```html
[style.height]="calc(100% - 57px)"
```

and getting back:

```
Error: Missing expected ) at column 14 in [calc(100% - 4px)]
```

seems like the '(' is not being escaped.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know the OP says they gave up on this but for anyone else who comes across this (this ranked high on Google for me), the answer here answers the question:

[Angular 2, Adding calc() as inline style. Unsafe interpolation using parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110028/angular-2-adding-calc-as-inline-style-unsafe-interpolation-using-parentheses)

The DOM Sanitizer is removing it, so it must be bypassed.

```
  import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
      this.someHeight = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("calc(100% - 57px)");
  }

  public someHeight: string;
```

or directly on the template:

```
[style.height]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('calc(100% - 57px)')"
```

Comment: Sanitizer should be set `public` if used in HTML template.

Answer (score 10):

You can also try using ngStyle instead:

```
[ngStyle]="{'height': 'calc(100% - 57px)'"}
```

Comment: this works but triggers the "after it has been checked" warning.

Comment: The problem probably lies somewhere else. It might happen when you use a variable inside ngStyle binding, and change it's value in a wrong lifecycle hook or during verification loop. Please check this article: 
https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Answer (score 5):

It needs to be a string, use `''`

```
[style.height]="'calc(100vh - ' + (checkedTaskTracker.checkedTasks.length > 0 ? '240px': '171px') + ')'"
```

Comment: seems like angular removes it, or sanitizes it, per the message appearing in the console: " sanitizing unsafe style value calc(100% - 57px);"
. Gave up and created a class for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use calc() in inline style then try this one for height or width

for height:

```
[ngStyle]="{'height': 'calc(100% - 57px)'}"
```

for width:

```
[ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc(100% - 57px)'}"
```